# Rails: Handling with big collections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have grouped contacts as collections with associated subscriptions.
These subscriptions are created and removed very often...

Each of the contacts collections can contain about 30.000 - 50.000 objects.

When creating subscriptions for 30.000 contacts, I iterate over the contacts collection and fill an array of sql values. After that, I manually execute a single sql insert statement with all these values:

```
sql_values = []
contacts.each do |contact|
  sql_values << ["(#{contact.id}, #{newsletter.id}, #{contact_group_id})"]
end
if sql_values.any?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "INSERT INTO subscriptions (contact_id, newsletter_id, contact_group_id) VALUES #{sql_values.join(", ")}"
  )
  sql_values = nil
end
```

The SQL insert takes just a second or so, thats okay.
The select on the contacts takes about 15 seconds on my development machine (8GB RAM).
The production machine just has 1GB RAM...

What would be your approach to reduce that time?

EDIT:
My problem is acts_as_taggable which joins the contacts with the tags table.
Anyone knows a good solution handling big collections with taggings on the objects?

Thank you!

Comment: That's a pretty weak production machine, I should say :)

Comment: how do you retrieve contacts? with an optimized query? couldn't you reverse the relationship to have the contact id in your current object?

Comment: I just noticed the problem. I am using acts_as_taggable for tagging the contacts. So the contacts collection is a very big sql query joining on the tags table. This query is so slow.

Comment: Is anyone using acts_as_taggable and is tagging big amount of data?
Perhaps creation of an index on the cached_taglist column optimizes the select?